help me understand the Spectral theorem for the laplacian
Let $u:Ω→R$ be the solution of:
$∆u=λu$ and $u=0$ on  $∂Ω$
Let $S=$ The spectrum of $∆ =$ all the values of $λ$ for which there is a solution.
If I understand correctly if $Ω$ is bounded, we have the following:

$S$ is countable
$u∈C^∞$
The set {$u∈C^∞ |∆u=λu ,λ∈S$} is an orthonormal basis for both $L^2 (Ω)$ and $H_0^1$ $(Ω)$
$λ ≥0$ $∀ λ∈S$

I know they are more properties, but I'm curious if I stated this correctly.
In addition if $Ω$ is unbounded then:
1.$S$ is uncountable and $S=(0,∞)$
2.$u ∈C^∞$
Basically, I think that we lose the countability and the “basis” if we let Ω be unfounded
I was wondering if there is a “substitute” for 3. Something like {$u∈C^∞ |∆u=λu ,λ∈S$} is dens in one but not the other ?

I believe $\lambda\ge 0$ if you consider the operator $-\Delta$, which is positive. This is clear in the 1D case, where $u''+\mu u=0$ with $u(0)=u(1)=0$ has solutions only for certain $\mu>0$.

As for your question, in the case of continuous spectrum you can represent any element of $L^2$ or $H_0^1$ as an integral w.r.t. the spectral family of projectors (as follows form the Spectral Theory).

@GReyes If I understand it correctly this means that if $F(x)∈L^2 (Ω)$ and $f(λ)=∫_Ω F(x)u(x,λ)dx⇒F(x)=∫_Sf(λ)u(x,λ)dλ $ . And if i'm correct the is it true that the eigenfunction are a dens set ?
